# Figure out transaction ID

Tags: transactions, transaction-id

How can I find out the ID of a transaction I just made?

I sent bitcoin to a site and they are requesting me to send the transaction ID to them.

How do I find it out?

Answer (score 3):

Some wallets have a function called something live "View on block explorer". For Electrum, you can see it if you right-click a transaction.

[image]

This will take you to a website on which you find your transaction ID. I drew a red ellipse around it so you know which number it is.

[image]

If your wallet doesn't have that functionality or you don't find it, simply copy the address you used to send the money and paste it into the search field on https://blockchain.info. You'll get to a page showing you all transactions that address has been involved in.

[image]

Green arrows mean that that address gained money, red arrows mean that that address lost money in the transaction.